# Wordpress plugin works only for logged users

Tags: wordpress

I'm using [Dave's Wordpress Live Search](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/daves-wordpress-live-search/).

The problem I have, is live search - it works only for logged users. If i'm logged in, plugin works fine. I found this line:

```
'ajaxURL' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php', is_ssl()),
```

which mean plugin is using `admin-ajax.php` and i think unlogged users haven't access to it.
I tried to define ajaxURL without `, is_ssl()`:

```
'ajaxURL' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
```

but didn't help.

Is it a problem with access to `wp-admin/admin-ajax.php`? How can i change it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case I would clone admin-ajax.php and rename it and remove all admin related conditionals from the file.

More specific:

- Make sure to include the new cloned file where required instead of
  the old one.
- Make sure also you are changing only the permissions
  levels from the file.
- The cloned file just put in the same directory as it is the admin-ajax.php, "wp-admin"

Good luck! :)

Comment: Many thanks, you save my day :) I made a copy of `/wp-admin/ajax.admin.php`, and changed `define('WP_ADMIN', true);` to `define('WP_ADMIN', false);`. Than i have changed in plugin file `ajaxURL` to use new file and it works.

Comment: Oh, thanks for the reply, I'm happy that you figured out the problem.

Answer (score 6):

This is old, but I was looking into this. 
Rather than changing the core, you can duplicate the hooks of the plugin and add ''no_priv'' versions. I am sure this is more elegant than duplicating a file in the core.

See: http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

From that page:

"Ajax on the Viewer-Facing Side
As of WordPress 2.8, there is a new hook similar to 'wp_ajax_my_action':

'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action' executes for users that are not logged in.
So, if you want it to fire for both visitors and logged-in users, you can do this:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action_callback');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'my_action_callback');"
```

Comment: As @Dynelight indicates above, you need to provide hooks for both admins and non-admins for anything using AJAX via the WP core. This is due to the fact that AJAX runs as admin via the core. Therefore you have to account for this with your code.